# Matching Tags using NLP

Tags: nlp

I am very new to NLP, any sort of help and comments would be appreciated.

Problem definition:

I have a set of predefined words/tags. Say for example, I have 1000 tags.

The user will input a sentence.

My program should return a set of tags relevant to the user input sentence.

My question is, what form of NLP should I use to get the desired output.

Comment: define "relevant".

Comment: @OliverMason by relevant, I meant tags which would describe a sentence. It could be an entity, context theme, or something like that. So the returned tags should be relatable to the sentence given by the user.

Comment: I think you have a text classification problem infront of you. You will have to create a dataset of the probable sentences your users can come up with and label them with the respective tags. Once you have this you can use any of the many text classification techniques(nb, log reg, or rnn/cnn etc) to train a model to predict your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short list of steps that can help you get started:

1) Investigate whether it is possible in your setting to build a vector space representation of your predefined words/tags. If you manage to do that, then you would be able to capture similarities between your predefined words/tags. Build this vector space.
(There are ways you can build such vector space representations. A recent web article that describes these representations is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/art-of-vector-representation-of-words-5e85c59fee5#:~:text=Words%20are%20represented%20by%20dense,used%20to%20represent%20each%20word.)).

1a) Suppose you can not build a vector space representation of your words/tags on your own, then you can use a generic vector space (like for example those used by [spacy](https://spacy.io), [here](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity)).

2) With your vector space representation in hand, parse your user input sentence and filter out all the tokens that do not appear in your predefined list of words/tags. Then form a vector with the remaining tags of your user input and check where your vector is located 
in the vector space defined in step 1). This will give you an idea about what to suggest as relevant in your output.